# Can't get Spring Boot application to work on Google Cloud Platform Flexible Environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm having trouble deploying my Spring Boot application on the Google Cloud Platform Flexible environment.

I run the following command to deploy: `mvn clean compile package -DskipTests appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp`

The `cloud-gcp` profile in my pom.xml has the following:

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>cloud-gcp</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <version>beta3</version>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

This is my `app.yaml` file located at `src/main/appengine/app.yaml`:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Here is my `application-gcp.properties`:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8080

# Datasource
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://google/xxx?cloudSqlInstance=xxx:europe-west4:xxx&autoReconnect=true&user=xxx&password=xxx&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&useSSL=false


server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

# Optimize start of application
spring.jmx.enabled=false

# Gcp configuration
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=xxx
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=xxx:europe-west4:xxx
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=true
```

The compilation is successful, no problems there. The problem occurs when I want to access my Spring Boot application. I constantly get a 502 Error. There is nothing in the logs that gives me a clue on what is wrong:

```
A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

A 2020-01-20T16:14:17Z  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)


com.xxx.api.xxxApplication       : Starting xxxApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on bc233766746a with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)

com.xxx.api.xxxApplication       : The following profiles are active: gcp

 .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.

.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 532ms. Found 17 repository interfaces.

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2c4dbf14] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4fb874e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@6b00f608' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9d02a00] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$abce0c46] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]

o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11326 ms

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [xxx:europe-west4:xxx] via SSL socket.

First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
```

This is the last lines I have in the logs. Nothing seems to break, no errors as far as I can tell. It seems to correctly connect to the Cloud SQL instance. I'm lost here. I've tried a lot of things, but I always get a 502 request from Spring Boot no matter what.

For information, the `/liveness_check` and `/readiness_check` always return 200 even when the server is not launched (which is strange...).

Tell me if you need any more informations on the configuration I am using.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: We finally solved our issue. For those who might have the same issue:

The problem was caused by our guava version. We add the version 18.0, which was problematic apparently. We added the version 28.2-jre in our pom.xml to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally solved our issue. For those who might have the same issue:

The problem was caused by our guava version. We add the version 18.0, which was problematic apparently. We added the following dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.2-jre</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, just doing some venting here but have been pulling my hair out for about 2 weeks now attempting to deploy a spring boot app to google cloud. It's incredibly nerve wracking to hear that a modification of a guava dependency could cause an application to not startup - even far worse make the logs go silent with no trace of what is going on. At the moment, I too am dealing with a situation where there are no application logs to be found and no trace of what is going wrong while just simply trying to hit an endpoint after what google cloud tells me is a successful deploy.

This comment and I'm sure to write others in the future is more aimed at getting other people to vent their frustration as google cloud support is non-existent unless you pay a premium for it. Making matters worse the product appears to be just plain terrible in terms of allowing developers insights into what is actually going wrong when a deployment doesn't work. I hope this gets their attention and I hope others voice their frustration as well because this product is simply unusable when it gives no indication of what is going wrong with a deployment. I've scoured their docs to no avail and it seems others have similar issues. Unfortunately my hands are tied by my client to use google cloud otherwise I would have migrated away from it after seeing first hand some of the very basic ways it is flawed. If you're in the process of evaluating a cloud product I would highly recommend not using google.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).